# copying from git remote to local server for release tool

Tags: git

I am in the process of releasing a tool. Using git, I have latest local master and updated remote master. When copying master to local server ( from where everybody can access it ), should it be copied from remote ( if so, how ? ) or from local. ?

Comment: Who/what would be using the master branch?  If you want to have it locally for development purposes, then just clone it.  If you need it deployed, this is another story.

Comment: Its the other story I am interested in .

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which source is now considered as the referenced one.

It usually is a remote server where the code was last pushed.

In that case, clone that a the local server, instead of copying from another local path.